# How to uninstall or remove Hadoop from Ubuntu ?

Tags: 14.04, hadoop

I have installed Hadoop-2.4.0 in my system(14.04), I want to remove it completely and reinstall it. If I have delete the configured folder hadoop, is it enough to remove hadoop in my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually I just delete the folder hadoop which given permission(*shown below*) to my HDFS user.

```
$ sudo rm -r -f /usr/local/hadoop/
```

Previously I extracted hadoop-2.4.0 and given permission for my HDFS user(hadoopuser - HDFS user),

```
$ sudo chown -R hadoopuser:hadoop hadoop
```

After that I removed user(hadoopuser) and group(hadoop)

```
root@ARUL-PC:~# deluser hadoopuser
Removing user `hadoopuser' ...
Warning: group `hadoop' has no more members.
Done.
root@ARUL-PC:~# deluser --group hadoop
Removing group `hadoop' ...
Done.
```

Now hadoop-2.4.0 not present in my system.

**Note :**
In my system, configured hadoop folder is `/usr/local/hadoop/`.

Comment: how to check that I removed Hadoop ?

Comment: But hadoop installs so may other things this is not really a complete uninstall is it?

Answer (score 1):

You can uninstall hadoop using:

```
sudo apt-get purge hadoop-2.4.*
```

This will remove all packages and configurations related to hadoop from your system.

Comment: It didn't worked.. actually I didn't installed my hadoop-2.4.0 from apt-get.. i hae manually installed and configured with [this link](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/)

Answer (score 0):

I struggled through this for longer than a while and then decided to share it here:

The trick is to basically delete all the symlinks pointing back to locations where HDP components reside since that is what causes 80% of the problem. Here is a step by step tutorial for that:

http://www.yourtechchick.com/hadoop/how-to-completely-remove-and-uninstall-hdp-components-hadoop-uninstall-on-linux-system/

Hope that helps!

Comment: link does not work